# Mock a local variable of a class using Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I have a class `A` that needs to be tested. The following is the definition of `A`:

```
public class A {
   private Human human = new Human(); 
   private SuperService service;

   public void methodOne() {
      service.processFile(human);
   } 
}
```

In my test I want to do something like this:

```
verify(service, times(1)).processFile(new Human());
```

Of course, I get a failure because of:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
Human$1@60cf80e7
Actual invocation has different arguments:
Human@302fec27
```

What I need is to set the `human` attribute to some specific value while it is being tested. Is there a way I can do this using mockito?

Comment: You can use `any(Human.class)` or use Power mockito for the `new Human`

Comment: look up argument matcher

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `service` is injectable

```
public class A {
   private Human human = new Human(); 
   private SuperService service;

   public A(SuperService service) {
       this.service = service;
   }

   public void methodOne() {
      service.processFile(human);
   } 
}
```

and has been properly mocked for the test

```
SuperService service =  mock(SuperService.class);

//...
```

You can use argument matcher when verifying the desired behavior

```
verify(service, times(1)).processFile(any(Human.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Mockito should compare arguments using the `equals()` method.

It appears that you have not implemented `Human.equals(Object other)` in your `Human` class, so it is comparing for equality using object references, which is not what you want.

The easiest fix is probably to implement `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) in your `Human` class. Then, you can pass in a `new Human()` with the properties you expect. Of course, you'd have to match against a human with the same propertiess, so it would actually be more like `verify(service, times(1)).processFile(new Human("John", "Smith"));`

---

Alternatively, simply use `any(Human.class)`, as suggested by user7. This will assert that the class matches, but will not assert on any of the fields within the class. That is, you'll know that `processFile()` was called with *some* Human, but you won't know whether it was called with a `Human` named John Smith or a `Human` named Jane Doe.

---

A third solution is to use an [argument captor](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.9/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) to capture the human class that it is called with. Then, you can assert individually on the fields you care about after. For example,

```
ArgumentCaptor<Human> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Human.class);
verify(service, times(1)).processFile(argument.capture());
assertEquals("John", argument.getValue().getName());
```